# Selenium tests are failing due to org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id on two different machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

```
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
    Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
    System info: host: 'chaos', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.106, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.XiR2sj}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:37450}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
    Session ID: cf2b9146e49c20dccbba70b575b2a393
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
        at com.tomtom.workflow.iris.uitest.pages.LoginService.logout(LoginService.java:66)
```

This problem is coming while loggingin and logged out into the application.
I have verified the chrome version/browser compatibility as well.
Some tome tests are running well and some time multiple tests ae getting failed due to this reason.

Options I have tried:

```
      checked Chrome driver compatibility: 
      browserVersion: 83.0.4103.106,chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39

      I have also checked the test;there is no use of driver.quit() and 
      driver.close()

      Selenium server version is "3.141.59".
      JDK version is "1.8".
```

Problem is coming in executing the below code:

```
      public void logout(String url) throws URISyntaxException {

    // when user is logged out
    URIBuilder uri = new URIBuilder(url);
    uri.setPath("uiris/logout");

    **$.driver().get().get(uri.toString());** //this line is causing the 
     issue.

    $("*[id='login.signIn']").waitUntil(5000).isPresent();
    LOG.info("log out is done successfully.");
}
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue.

```
 The issue is not reproduced, if the tests are run on the local machine. But 
 when tests are running on two different Jenkins created machines in 
 parallel, then multiple tests are getting failed due to this problem only on 
 one machine.
```

Iam not able  to identitify,if theerei somethng wrong with the machne on which tests are running or there is some issue withn the chrome driver.

Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: Can you change `$.driver().get().get(uri.toString());` to `$.driver().get(uri.toString());` and retest please?

Comment: How do you make sure that you are not calling `driver.close()`? If you run your tests in parallel your tests might use shared driver that is getting closed while another test is still running.

Comment: @AlexeyR.  I checked the test code. There is no use of driver.close() in the code. Instead, after each test log out is performed from the application and in the starting login to the application is performed.

Comment: `$.driver().get(uri.toString())` did not work for me. I tried `$.url(uri.toString());` and it worked for me. Thankyou !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that both machines are using the same chrome session